# How to show bar of graph in different colour when it reaches threshold level in high charts in JS?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how to display a bar of graph in different color when it reaches level 100. it should show in different color (red). how to change my code to show a bar in red color in High Charts. All normal level bars should be in one color and threshold reached levels in red color.

JS fiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/h5t4c8hj/

code

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Chart.update'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Plain'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        colorByPoint: false,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        showInLegend: false
    }]

});


$('#plain').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: false,
            polar: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Plain'
        }
    });
});

$('#inverted').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            polar: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Inverted'
        }
    });
});

$('#polar').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: false,
            polar: true
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Polar'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Chart.update'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Plain'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        colorByPoint: false,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        showInLegend: false
    }]

}, function(chart) {
    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, data) {
        if (data.y >= 100)
            data.update({
                color: 'red'
            });
    })
});

$('#plain').click(function() {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: false,
            polar: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Plain'
        }
    });
});

$('#inverted').click(function() {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            polar: false
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Inverted'
        }
    });
});

$('#polar').click(function() {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            inverted: false,
            polar: true
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Polar'
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 320px;
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<button id="plain">Plain</button>
<button id="inverted">Inverted</button>
<button id="polar">Polar</button>
```

You can use `data.update`

Comment: can u once check my real code i'm getting unable to fix in my code
http://jsfiddle.net/h5t4c8hj/1/

Comment: @vinilapriya check this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/h5t4c8hj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code on [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893319/change-the-color-of-bar-on-condition-in-highcharts):

```
let max = 100;

$.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i,data){

  if(data.y > max)
    data.graphic.attr({
      fill:'red'
    });

});
```

[image]

But it's not fully working when changing graph type. I'll get back to you when I have more information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `zones`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/3o2845bw/

Comment: very nice answer , but it will only work for only1 color but not for multi color option like if x >90  red, x>80 yellow

Comment: @vinilapriya You can easily modify zones array to meet your requirements. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/67fo3nst/.